# How to handle action bar in back button press in fragment in android

Tags: android

I have activity adding A fragment from A fragment it is going to a B fragment.I have different action bar icon and title in A and B fragment.While pressing back button from B fragment How to maintain the action bar state of A

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set your ActionBar title in your Activity from Fragment onCreate method. In each Fragment, onCreate, you can call the following method,

```
 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(TITLE);
```

And define this method in your Activity,

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
  getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setTitle(title);
   // Or getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

To maintain the state, you need to call this in each Fragment onCreate, as you do replace FragmentTransaction which removes and adds a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private String[] tabs = { "firstFragment", "secondFragment" };
  // Adding Tabs
  //if use default cutom
    for (String tab : tabs) {
      getActionBar().addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab).setTabListener(this))                                                                     
    }
```